# Manual for Age of Wonders?

Tags: age-of-wonders

I've got a copy of the original Age of Wonders game. Is there a place online where I can find the manual for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://aow.heavengames.com/downloads/showfile.php?fileid=811) is a complete transcript of the manual in .txt format.

[Here](http://aggelonware.free.fr/aow/aowadden23.pdf) is the manual addendum in .pdf format.

Comment: @penyuan - You're very welcome

Comment: Just wish there's a manual that's got a little formatting than pure text. :)

Answer (score 5):

[Replacementdocs.com](http://www.replacementdocs.com) offers a lot of manuals, among them [the Age of Wonders manual in PDF format](http://www.replacementdocs.com/download.php?view.280).